# qgridlayout background image? pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qgridlayout

Is it possible to load a background image in qgridlayout? I have a couple of button inside a gridlayout, i wan to load a background image depending on  the size of the whole gridlayout.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Q*Layout`s are not widgets, so no, you can't put a background on them. However you'll (probably) have a widget that'll have your layout. You can put a background on it. See the [`setStyleSheet`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) method for `QWidget`s.